# How to select and move multiple vertices

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm wondering how to select and move multiple vertices. Since it is a 3d shape but I'm going off a picture that I'm tracing. I just don't want to manually select each vertex each time.

Answer (score 11):

There are multiple ways of doing this told below:
**Box select**: press the <kbd>B</kbd> key and you can click and drag a square that will select everything inside.

**Circle select**: press the <kbd>C</kbd> key, and your mouse will change to a circle, anything clicked inside the circle will be selected.

**Holding shift**: You can manually select vertices while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> down to keep the previous selections as well.

**Select Linked**: With one vertex selected of an object and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> you will select the whole object itself that is part of that one vertices you selected at the start.

It seems you are a beginner these option should be enough and to get you started, then you can use the transformation manipulators (using arrows on the screen) or press the <kbd>G</kbd> while selected to move it as well.

Comment: I think pressing G is what the asker is getting after. Is there a way to do the move along a particular axis without changing the viewport angle?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways o do this. My favorite is Circle select.

To use, hit <kbd>C</kbd> a small circle appears, click and drag it over the vertices you want to grab. All the vertecies in the radius of the circle will be selected. If you select a vertex you didn't need, middle click on it to deselect. You can scroll your mouse wheel in and out to change the size of the circle.

[image]

Right click to end circle select mode.

Answer (score 3):

Another great one is to select one vertex close to the center of what you will be editing, and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Num+</kbd> to increase your selection. if you accidentally select more than you meant to,  just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Num-</kbd> to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Other way is to use **<kbd>B</kbd>** Click and drag.
Press **<kbd>Esc</kbd>** to end selection.
[image]

Comment: this only describes how to select a vertex, not how to move the selected vertex

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>B</kbd> to acesse the box tool and select all you want (everything visible inside the box will be selected), then use the **move/grab** tool to move them pressing <kbd>G</kbd>