# Problem at Selecting Points after Extruding

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am very new to Blender and googled my Problem now over 2 hours, but didnt found anything. That's my Problem:

I extruded my Mesh and want to Merge to Points. When i am about to select my two Points, the Program selects all Points along the extruding Path.

[image]

How can i change this setting and just select only the two Points?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26781/how-to-select-and-move-multiple-vertices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things to keep in mind in your case.

First, it seems you're holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while selecting vertices. This means you select these vertices *and* [every vertice located along the shortest path between them](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#path-selection).

To select only 2 vertices you should hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking on the vertices.

[image]

Second, you have double vertices in your mesh, at least those which are selected. Select all, use <kbd>W</kbd> and in the menu choose *Remove Doubles*. Read similar question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38416/my-vertices-disconnect).

Comment: You are my Hero this Evening! Thanks alot, Sir!

Comment: @Mr Zak What kind of keyboard capture soft you use?

Comment: @Gonzou I downloaded [KeyCastOW](https://brookhong.github.io/2014/04/28/keycast-on-windows.html) (because I'm on Windows) along with Screencast addon because I didn't manage to make Screencast display `Shift` or `Ctrl` in such scenarios. It works for `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Shift`+`C` of course, but not in this case.